# File I/O troubles using Parallel.for loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, file-io, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have a console app that is scheduled to process a large number of flat files. To improve performance,  I provided the option to use parallel processing. It has dramatically improved performance. However, it is now causing weird errors when certain iterations are copying and deleting a file. I do not know why this is happening or how to fix it. I don't see why the threads that the iterations are assigned to would clash as each file and associated ids is different. Here is my basic code and error:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, fileCount, i =>
                        {
                            dxmtId = Convert.ToInt32(dxmtIds[i]);
                            iflId = Convert.ToInt32(iflIds[i]);
                            islId = Convert.ToInt32(islIds[i]);
                            fileName = fileNames[i].ToString();

                            LoadFileIntoDatabase(monitorId, islId, dxmtId, iflId, fileName);

                        });
    }
    private static void LoadFileIntoDatabase (int procId, int islId, int dxmtId, iflId, fileName )
    {
        string fileNameDone = fileName + ".done";

        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
             // code for successfully loading file 
             myCommand = @"CMD.EXE";
             ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(myCommand)
                    {
                        WorkingDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExportPath"].ToString(),
                        Arguments = @"/c SQLLDR CONTROL=" + controlFileWithPath + " PARFILE=" + parFileWithPath,
                        //RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        RedirectStandardError = true,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        CreateNoWindow = true
                    };

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
            exitCode = process.ExitCode;
            try 
            {
                File.Copy(fileName, fileNameDone, true); //rename file to .done
                File.Delete(fileName); //delete original file
            }
            catch (exception ex)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(@"c:\temp\fileerrors.txt", ex.Message + " " + " on copying or deleting file name: " + fileName +  Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
```

Errors are either 1) "cannot find file... " or 2) "the process cannot access the file... "

Any advice on how to fix/diagnose what is happening?

Comment: In your `Arguments`, what values do `controlFileWithPath` etc. have? It might be necessary to quote the file path, e.g. executing the command `cmd.exe /c SQLLDR CONTROL="C:\temp\some file.txt"` if the path has spaces in it. If the operations are really independent from each other, parallelizing them should be fine. However, if e.g. the `SQLLDR` programm tries to write to a database in parallel, that might again give you some probems.

Comment: i think the issue could well be that the process of `File.Copy()` may still have a handle on the original file, thus the `File.Delete()` is failing as the copy function is not waited upon to complete. maybe you should use `File.Move()` instead (single action)??. just an inkling

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt :     controlFileWithPath and parFileWithPath are temp metadata files with paths that I generate from another function, not listed in this code. They return paths with no spaces, eg. "c:\\temp\\634b99e3-77a7-43aa-b9d7-c60735c13e48.ctl" and are only used by sql loader to load the file. 

The errors are occurring during the File.Copy/File.Delete statements, which are on the actual file I loaded (not the metadata files you are asking about). 

I will have to look into the idea that sqlldr might be doing in parallel. I don't think that is the default behavior though. thanks

Comment: @jimtollan     I was using .Move() before, but I will try that again now and see if it changes anything. thanks

Comment: curious to know if you ever resolved this issue??

Comment: Actually, no. I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around why this isn't working and I created some small simulation code to explain. I have some code that simulates my problem, but it's too large for a comment. Is my only option to post a new question? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue could well be that the process of `File.Copy()` still has a handle on the original file, thus the `File.Delete()` is failing.

I would suggest that you use `File.Move()` instead as this is actually less resource intensive. Internally, `File.Move()` uses the `Win32Native.MoveFile` function, which does a rename on the file system. If you use `File.Copy()`, you will actually be copying the data on the disk, which will be more resource-intensive and slower. However, you should avoid `File.Move()` if you need to retain two copies of the data (which in your example appears NOT to be the case).

Your required code change would look a bit like this:

```
try
{
    File.Move(fileName, fileNameDone);
}
```

You may also want to look more closely at the `catch` block and target known errors more cloely, i.e.

```
catch (IOException ex)
{
    // specific error type expected
}
```

Hope this takes you a stage further.

Comment: File.Move is doing the same thing. Interestingly, when I looked in the error file that I am create in the catch block, in certain cases I am seeing multiple entries of the error "could not find file xxxx" for the same file, AND in my output directory there is indeed a .done file for that file. So it actually worked and moved the file, but then it tried it again and obviously failed because the file was not there any more. I checked my list and I do not have duplicate names. It appears that somehow threads are tying to process the same file. I don't get it!

Comment: Is it possible to see if sql loader has a handle on the file when my app attempts to move it?

Comment: I have a little more information, hopefully someone can steer me right. 1. Every single File.Move() statement that caused an error actually worked (i've no clue what to make of that). 2. When I took the sql loader processing out of my code there are zero errors. Obviously it has something to do with the many threads launching sql loader. But I still have no clue how the same file could be attempted twice when the file names are distinct: 

            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit(); //should this cause any handles to release?

Comment: could it be that your error is actually happening due to the fileerrors.txt being locked on a previous error and then a subsequent attempt fails on trying to write to it. can't see any other glaring issues

Comment: I think I've found the problem. It's in the control files we are passing to sql loader.Turns out there are several duplicate file names in those files, so when running in parallel, conceivably 2+ threads are trying to process the same file virtually at the same time. I check the file's existence, process it, then rename it when it's done, so perhaps the thread just behind it is making it in there, loading it again and trying to rename it after it's just been re-named. Hence the "can't find file" and "access denied" errors. And in serial, naturally there is no issue. 

Thanks for your input.

Comment: it might be an idea to use a concurrent dictionary and add the filename to it just before running the process. so, on entering the process request, you'd check for the existence of the filename in the CD and only add and run if it wasn't present... if this works, will add it to my answer for other users experiencing similar issues

Comment: Thanks, but I think the solution is to fix the dba code that is generating the control file content so there are no duplicates. I don't think this is an issue with parallel coding so much as buggy code.

Comment: I should add/clarify that the dba is creating the control file based on its own logic and is putting the path name inside that file. The code that I am working with to iterate through the list of files does not contain duplicates. Therefore, the cd in this case would not help. I like the idea though, I've never heard of the cd. I'm sure it would work if my list of filenames contained duplicates.

Comment: yeah - the concurrent dictionary is designed for exactly the tasks you are faced with; parallel processing where the logic does not have a linear or predictable path. i use it extensively when doing parallel task based operations -invaluable